# How can I Access Database in BroadcastReceiver Class in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` class to receive incoming call. I want to compare the incoming number with a numbers from my database. Now I can't understand how to use database in `BroadcastReceiver` class.
I make object of `DBAdapter` class in `onReceive()` method in this way:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(contenxt);
  Cursor c = d.getAllData();
  while(c.moveToFirst){
      do{
            Log.v("Data : "+c.getString(2));
        }
        while(c.moveToNext);
  }
}
```

Above code snippet throws NullPointerException. Please somebody help me to achieve this.

Comment: in that which line you getting null pointer exception

Comment: Don't use `database` in `BroadcastReceiver` start a `service` instead where you work with `database`.

Comment: in the line c.moveToFirst ..here i have get error nullpointer...

Comment: Thank you Biegleux to give me such a greate suggetion but i am new to android can u give a way to how can i need to make a Service for this case .....thank you again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The greate and simplest way is below,

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("PhoneDB2", 0, null);
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * From checkedNumbers", null);

    if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

        } while(cur.moveToNext())
    }
}
```

This is the great solution of above problem..................