# I have problem with sqlite database i want to read my database rows and set the no of rows in notification

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications

I want to get a notification "You have n no.of orders" this n is the no.of rows in SQLite table but I getting nullPointerException when notification time.how to solve this ..thanks in advanace
notification_reiever.java

```
              public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] v = {500,1000};
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int todayYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int todayMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH+1);
    int todayDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    String todayDateString=Integer.toString(todayDate).trim()+Integer.toString(todayMonth+1).trim()+Integer.toString(todayYear).trim();
   long countRows= myDb.countRows(todayDateString);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add)
            .setContentTitle("Saffron")
            .setContentText("Good morning! You have "+countRows+"orders on today hope you completed all.")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSound)
            .setVibrate(v);
    notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
}
```

DatabaseHeper.java

```
public long countRows(String todayDate)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();

    long countRowsNo= DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,TABLE_NAME,todayDate);
    return  countRowsNo;

}
```

Logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.android.saffrondesigner.Notification_reciever: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2580)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.android.saffrondesigner.Notification_reciever.onReceive(Notification_reciever.java:32)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where you initialize the database instance(myDb)? check the database instance is initialized or not.
check this [How to use database inside the onReceive method] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719981/how-can-i-access-database-in-broadcastreceiver-class-in-android)

Comment: The error happens in line 32 in your notification receiver. Which specific line is that?

Comment: @jmart  long countRows=myDb.countRows(); is 32th line..